# Form not submitting data through ORM (prisma) to database

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, forms, next.js, prisma

I've spent the last day trying to figure this one out, with little progress made. I'm using Next.js 13.

I've successfully connected my app to a Postgres Database, set up the Prisma schema and tested a migration with a `seed.ts` file.

Now my `route.js` file has been causing me all kinds of errors, and while I can't get an error to display in the console when the form is submitted; no data is being sent through my sign-up form into the database, and I have no idea why.

I've already gone through numerous Next.js 13 API forum posts on here, google search, and watched a few YouTube videos. There appears to be an issue with the `route.js` file and maybe the API handler, but I don't know what to debug at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

route.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(req) {
    const { name, password, email } = req.body;
    try {

        const user = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                name,
                email,
                password
            },
        });
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'method allow' })
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'error' })
        
    }
}
```

page.js (containing the form):

```
"use client";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function SignUp() {
    const { register, reset, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const router = useRouter();
 
    const onSubmit = async data => {
        console.log(data);

        const user = await fetch("api/createuser", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })

        /*if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
            router.push("/login"); 
        }
        reset();

        */
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="signUp">Sign up</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="signUpForm">
                <input
                    {...register("name", { required: true })} id="first" placeholder="Name"
                    aria-invalid={errors.name ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.name?.type === 'required' && <p className="errorMessageOne" role="alert">First name is required</p>}

                <input {...register("mail", { required: true })} type="mail" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"
                    aria-invalid={errors.mail ? "true" : "false"} />
                {errors.mail && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Please enter a valid email address</p>}

                <input {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 4 })} id="password" placeholder="Password must contain a minimum of 8 characters"
                    aria-invalid={errors.password ? "true" : "false"} />
                {errors.password && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Please enter a valid password</p>}

                <button type="submit" className="signSubmit">Submit</button>
                <p className="alreadyText"> Already have an account? <Link href="/login"><span>Login</span></Link></p>
            </form>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did in your API route handler to grab the JSON data sent by the form is the way with the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router. Since you are using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, you do it as below, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#request-body):

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function POST(request) {
  const { name, password, email } = await request.json()
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that has removed the error, but no data appears to be sending to the database.

Comment: Is your prisma client correctly configured?

Comment: it is - the problem after all that was the field names in the form, not matching the json object, I will provide the corrected code - as well as adding your correction in the route.js file, so thanks once again for the help.

Comment: It's my pleasure @jvs789789 :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that comes across this issue, here is the code that resolved my issue - the form now submits the form data, through Prisma, into my local Postgres database

Route.js - Server component

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(request) {

    const { name, password, email } = await request.json()

    const user = {
        name,
        email,
        password,
    }

    let createUser = await prisma.user.create({ data: user })


    return NextResponse.json(user)

}
```

page.js - Client Componenent

```
"use client"

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; 
import Link from "next/link";

export default function SignUp() {
    const { register, reset, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const router = useRouter();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/api/createuser", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
              
                router.push("/login");
                reset();
            } else {
              
                console.error("Registration failed");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="signUp">Sign up</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="signUpForm">
                <input
                    {...register("name", { required: true })}
                    id="first"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    aria-invalid={errors.name ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.name?.type === 'required' && <p className="errorMessageOne" role="alert">First name is required</p>}

                <input
                    {...register("email", { required: true })}
                    type="email" 
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    aria-invalid={errors.email ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.email && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Please enter a valid email address</p>}

                <input
                    {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 4 })}
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Password must contain a minimum of 8 characters"
                    aria-invalid={errors.password ? "true" : "false"}
                />
                {errors.password && <p className="errorMessage" role="alert">Please enter a valid password</p>}

                <button type="submit" className="signSubmit">Submit</button>
                <p className="alreadyText"> Already have an account? <Link href="/login"><span>Login</span></Link></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```